# How can I increase the number of leading spaces for each new line printed?

Tags: python, string

I want to print the letter "H" 10 times (preferably in a loop) but for every new line that gets printed, the "H" has to move one space. How can I do this?

Here is  my original code:

```
for a in range(0,10):
    b=" "
    b+="  "
    print(b+"H");
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework. In the loop you need a way of keeping track of how many spaces to indent the "H". And during each iteration you will have to increment this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this simply by multiplying the index by the number of spaces you want:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
    print i * " " + "H"

H
 H
  H
   H
    H
     H
      H
       H
        H
         H
```